# Adapter makes all the items unsorted after sorting the items in SQLite Database?

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite, oop

I am making an android based note taking application with categories. I am supposed to sort the categories according to title and date created. I have inserted the date created column in category table in the sqlite database. i have also used the query by using ORDER BY clause and whenever I click on the Title and Date Created option from options menu. The adapter is sorted accordingly. But whenever I restart the application the sorted adapter resets and all the items are appeared unsorted, as the adapter is set in onCreate method.
I want to keep the state of sorted adapter, but unable to understand the logic.

I have tried all the possible solutions that comes in my mind, I have used a global variable chkSort in it to determine which query is to be implemented. But whenever I restart the app this variable is initialized to "default and again the unsorted adapter is set.

This is my snippet of two classes:

```
public class MainScreen extends AppCompatActivity
{
ArrayList<DataModelCategory> lists = new ArrayList<>();
String query,chkSort="default";
RecyclerView recyclerView;
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
 recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerMain);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 4);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this, lists);
        recyclerAdapter=new RecyclerAdapter(this,lists);

            lists.clear();
            final DataAdapterCategory db = new DataAdapterCategory(getApplicationContext());
            db.openDB();
            Cursor cursor = db.getAllData(chkSort);
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                int id = cursor.getInt(0);
                String categName = cursor.getString(1);
                DataModelCategory dataModelCategory = new DataModelCategory(id, categName);
                lists.add(dataModelCategory);

            }
            if (!(lists.size() < 1)) {
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            else {
                txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            db.closeDB();

   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.action_notebook: {
                // create an alert builder
                AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alertBuilder.setTitle("New notebook");
                alertBuilder.setCancelable(false);

                // set the custom layout
                final View customLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.notebook_dialog, null);
                alertBuilder.setView(customLayout);

                // add a button
                alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                        EditText editText = customLayout.findViewById(R.id.editName);
                        String label = editText.getText().toString();
                        if (label.trim().length() > 0) {
                            // send data from the AlertDialog to the Activity


                            sendDialogDataToActivity(editText.getText().toString());

                            save(editText.getText().toString());
                            lists.clear();
                            DataAdapterCategory db = new DataAdapterCategory(getApplicationContext());
                            db.openDB();
                            Cursor cursor = db.getAllData(chkSort);
                            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                                int id = cursor.getInt(0);
                                String categName = cursor.getString(1);
                                DataModelCategory dataModelCategory = new DataModelCategory(id, categName);
                                lists.add(dataModelCategory);

                            }
                            if (!(lists.size() < 1)) {

                                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                //startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class));
                                txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }

                            db.closeDB();
                            // database handler
                            DatabaseHandler dbs = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                            // inserting new label into database
                            dbs.insertLabel(label);
                            // Hiding the keyboard
                            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                                    getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
                            // loading spinner with newly added data
                            //  loadSpinnerData();
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter label name.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    }
                });
                // negative button
                alertBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                // create and show the alert dialog
                AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
            break;
}
}
}
```

```
public class DataAdapterCategory extends AppCompatActivity
{

Context c;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    DBHelperText helper;

    public DataAdapterCategory(Context c) {
        this.c = c;
        helper=new DBHelperText(c);
    }

//INSERT
    public long add(String categoryName,String date)
    {
        try
        {
            ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
            cv.put(Constants.CATEGORY_NAME,categoryName);
            cv.put(Constants.CATEGORY_DATE,date);
            return db.insert(Constants.TB_NAME_CAT,Constants.ROW_ID_CAT,cv);
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
 //RETRIEVE OR VIEW
    public Cursor getAllData(String chkSort)
    {
        String[] columns={Constants.ROW_ID_CAT,Constants.CATEGORY_NAME,Constants.CATEGORY_DATE};
        if (chkSort.equals("Title"))
        {
            return db.query(Constants.TB_NAME_CAT,columns,null,null,null,null,Constants.CATEGORY_NAME + " ASC");
        }
        else if (chkSort.equals("DateCreated"))
        {
            return db.query(Constants.TB_NAME_CAT,columns,null,null,null,null,Constants.CATEGORY_DATE + " DESC");
        }
        else
        {
            return db.query(Constants.TB_NAME_CAT,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
        }

    }
}
```

I want to keep the sorted adapter even after restarting the app. For example if the user has clicked on the sort by options menu and clicked to sort the categories according to date created from alert dialog then after restarting the app the adapter should appear sorted according to date created.
But unfortunately I am unable to understand that how should it be done because everytime I start app it becomes unsorted.
Where should I set the adapter in this case.

Comment: you could store the sorting method in shared preferences and then when app starts get this storing method from shared prefs and assign it to the `chkSort` variable

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values and try to apply to your needs :)

Comment: When you are getting the data from the Local DB to use a query for sorting there itself and send it to the adapter @MehwishMustafa

Comment: Why is `DataAdapterCategory` an `AppCompatActivity`?